# Disable download confirmation box in IE

Tags: windows-8.1, browser, internet-explorer-11

If we download any file, IE will ask whether to open or save the file. How I can make default option as Save and avoid this confirmation box?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could give more details. What have you researched and/or attempted so far? What version of Windows and IE?

Comment: Windows 8, IE 11. I am starting IE in kiosk mode. User can click a link to download a text file. I want it to be saved in default download location without confirmation box "Do you want to save/open"

Comment: It is understood what you want. We just needed more details about the system you are working with. What have you tried so far? Is this same file being downloaded each time?